# Python: how to input python-code part like \input in Tex?

Tags: python, input

I want to input code in Python like `\input{Sources/file.tex}`. How can I do it in Python?

**[added]**

Suppose I want to input data to: `print("My data is here"+<input data here>)`.

**Data**

```
1, 3, 5, 5, 6
```

Comment: what does your addition even mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was clearly too broad, as the variety of replies hint -- none of them fully attack the question. The jchl targets the scenario where you get python-code to be executed. The THC4k addresses the situation where you want to use outside objects from modules. muckabout's reply is bad practice, as Xavier Ho mentioned, why on earth it uses `import` when it could use `exec` as well, the principle of least privileges to the dogs. One thing is still missing, probably because of the conflict between the term `python-code` in the title and the addition of `data` containing integers -- it is hard to claim that data is `python-code` but the code explains how to `input` data, `evaluations` and `executable` code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Description: it works like the input -thing in Tex,
# you can fetch outside executable code, data or anything you like.
# Sorry I don't know precisely how input(things) works, maybe misusing terms
# or exaggerating.
#
# The reason why I wanted input -style thing is because I wanted to use more
# Python to write my lab-reports. Now, I don't need to mess data with 
# executions and evalutions and data can be in clean files.


#TRIAL 1: Execution and Evaluation not from a file

executeMe="print('hello'); a = 'If you see me, it works'";

exec( executeMe )
print(a);

#TRIAL 2: printing file content
#
# and now with files
#
# $ cat IwillPrint007fromFile
# 007

f = open('./IwillPrint007fromFile', 'r');
msg = f.read()

print("If 007 == " + msg + " it works!");


# TRIAL 3: Evaluation from a file
#
# $cat IwillEvaluateSthing.py
# #!/usr/bin/python
# #
# # Description: 
# 
# 
# evaluateMe = "If you see me again, you are breaking the rules of Sky."

f = open('./IwillEvaluateSthing.py', 'r');
exec(f.read());
print(evaluateMe);
```

Answer (score 4):

The built-in `execfile` function does what you ask, for example:

```
filename = "Sources/file.py"
execfile( filename )
```

This will execute the code from `Sources/file.py` almost as if that code were embedded in the current file, and is thus very similar to `#include` in C or `\input` in LaTeX.

Note that `execfile` also permits two optional arguments allowing you to specify the globals and locals dicts that the code should be executed with respect to, but in most cases this is not necessary.  See `pydoc execfile` for details.

There are occasional legitimate reasons to want to use `execfile`.  However, for the purpose of structuring large Python programs, it is conventional to separate your code into modules placed somewhere in the PYTHONPATH and to load them using the `import` statement rather than executing them with `execfile`.  The advantages of `import` over `execfile` include:

- Imported functions get qualified with the name of the module, e.g. `module.myfunction` instead of just `myfunction`.
- Your code doesn't need to hard-code where in the filesystem the file is located.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in Python. You can `import` objects from other modules.

*otherfile.py:*

```
def print_hello():
    print "Hello World!"
```

*main.py*

```
import otherfile
otherfile.print_hello() # prints Hello World!
```

See the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Extending THC4k's answer, Python's import isn't just a copy-and-paste pre-processor like C #include. Instead Python will actually process the names of the classes and functions and remember them in a look-up dict so you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have code in "my_file.py".  Any line which is not in a method WILL get executed when you do:

```
import my_file
```

So for example if my_file.py has the following code in it:

```
print "hello"
```

Then in the interpreter you type:

```
import my_file
```

You will see "hello".

Comment: This is bad practice, though.

Comment: In most contexts, yes.  But latex isn't exactly an advanced programming language :)